# Is there a zero constant in the GMP library?

Tags: constants, gmp

In a program, I have to check whether a certain number is equal to zero. One way to do it is to just initialise an `mpz_t` and check whether the original number equals it. But surely there is a zero constant in GMP, like `BigInteger.ZERO` in Java & Kotlin?

(Somehow [this](https://gmplib.org/manual/Useful-Macros-and-Constants) page doesn't contain what I want; I did "check the fine manual" & use a search engine, for those of you who adhere to the standard level of politeness on this page.)

Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT: I just learned that one may compare an mpz_t to an integer, so that one may do something like `mpz_cmp_ui(variable, 0) == 0`. The solutions given by the answer by Marc Glisse are probably even faster.

Comment: With gcc, if you enable optimizations, `mpz_cmp_ui(variable, 0)` should generate the same code as `mpz_sgn(variable)` thanks to some `__builtin_constant_p` magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test if `z` is zero, you can test `mpz_sgn(z)==0` or `mpz_size(z)==0`, you don't need an mpz_t with value 0. As you noticed, you can also compare `z` to a native integer with `mpz_cmp_ui` or `mpz_cmp_si`.

There is no predefined constant 0. Calling `mpz_init` is cheap enough (no allocation) to create a zero if you need one.

Comment: Definitely helpful (hence +1), but I'll click the check mark only after it has been clarified that such a constant does not exist. (Unfortunately, a limb may contain more than one bit, whence your 2nd trick doesn't seem to function in order to check whether a variable equals 1.)

Comment: (Even though one may compare to integers, as I just learned.)

Comment: @AlgebraicsAnonymous: And to be clear, on top of comparisons, basically every `mpz_t`-operation has variants with `_ui` or `_si` suffixes (or infixes in some complicated cases) that let you avoid creating an `mpz_t` for performing math with a value that fits in an `unsigned long` or `long` respectively, so you don't need `mpz_t` constants for `0` or `1` or `-1` no matter what you're doing, which is why they don't provide one.